# Can a ListenableFuture chain handle inner ExecutionException?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, guava, future

I am provided with an api (**fnGrpc**) that performs a gRPC call and returns a `ListenableFuture` that resolves to some value **v** (the implementation of which is fixed and unmodifiable).

I want to provide a helper function (**fnHelper**) that:

1. does some transformational processing on the gRPC result and itself returns a `ListenableFuture` that resolves to the transformed value **t1**.
2. handles failure of the gRPC call, and returns some other value **t2** instead of having **fnHelper**'s caller see an `ExecutionException`.

I can solve (1) by using `Futures.transform()`:

```
package myHelper;

ListenableFuture<T> fnHelper() {
  return Futures.transform(fnGrpc(), new Function<V, T>() {
    @Override
    public T apply(V v) {
      T t1 = f(v);
      return t1;
    }
  });
}
```

and the caller:

```
package myApp;

// ...

try {
  T t = fnHelper().get();
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
  // ...
}
```

**How can I achieve (2) whilst still having fnHelper return a `ListenableFuture` and remain non-blocking?**

I could have **fnHelper** itself create an additional thread within which I would call `.get()` on **fnGrpc**, but is there another way that avoids this additional thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Guava, but it seems you can do that using the same [`Futures`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html) utility class, in particular the method [`catchingAsync`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#catchingAsync-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-java.lang.Class-com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction-java.util.concurrent.Executor-), where you can pass a function that returns a `ListenableFuture` with the fallback value (`t2`):

```
ListenableFuture<Integer> faultTolerantFuture = Futures.catchingAsync(originalFuture,
                       Exception.class, x -> immediateFuture(t2), executor);
```

You should then be able to chain this with the `transform` method, which does the transformation:

```
ListenableFuture<T> fnHelper() {
    return Futures.catching(Futures.transform(fnGrpc(), new Function<V, T>() {
        @Override
        public T apply(V v) {
            T t1 = f(v);
            return t1;
        }
    }),
    Exception.class, x -> immediateFuture(t2));
}
```

**Note:** In the last snippet, I used `catching` instead of `catchingAsync` to be consistent with the code in your question, and I didn't specify an executor. You probably need to use the methods with the *`Async`* suffix for non-blocking processing.